# nib file not working after renaming

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just renamed my .h .m and .xib files and now the .xib file doesn't work anymore, as it's apperently still connected to the old file names.

Any idea why this is and how do I connect it to the new name of the .h and .m files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was your main .xib file, look in your plist file and/or the application settings in Xcode. (I believe it's in project settings -> build target -> summary -> main interface)

If it was a xib file you used in your code, look for that code (where you instantiate the viewcontroller) and change the name there.

Comment: It a file I have created myself, but I can't see where the old name is in my code. My xib file has the same name as my .h and .m

Comment: It's often used as `[[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];` (minus the autorelease on iOS 5 with ARC) - look for that in your code.